# WebDriver: how to wait for text to disappear in the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a field that dynamically changes it's text. I need a way to wait for the text to be changed. I'm not aware about what text will appear, but I know what text is currently there. So i'd like to wait for it to disappear in the element. Is there a way for this?

Comment: OK, i've used wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, text)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can Try [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)  function `textToBePresentInElement` and add a `not`, like,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(
    ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element,"textToBePresent")));
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do this... use the built-in functions provided for scenarios just like this.

Comment: Sorry, I down voted this answer. I totally missed the `not` in the code. Please make a small edit so that I can remove my downvote. I'll be happy to upvote instead. this is correct.