# WaitForTextNotPresent with Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium3

I have tried to implement something then wait until a special text not more displayed on the webpage.

My solution for `waitForTextPresent` works fine:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("text");
```

But I search the solution to negate it, please help me.

Comment: That's not a wait, that's a validation. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: How to implement waitForText and waitForNotText with Webdriver java

Comment: You need to put that description in your question and add some more details. What have you tried? Where are your code attempts? What was the result?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461228/webdriver-how-to-wait-for-text-to-disappear-in-the-element

Answer (score 0):

`.contains()` returns a boolean, so negate it as usual `!driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("text");`

Comment: I need the same method like the in Selenium IDE, -> waitForTextNotPresent

Comment: You should add Selenium IDE as a part of your question. Anyways, `waitForTextPresent` is deprecated, use `waitForText` and `waitForNotText`.

Comment: How to implement waitForText and waitForNotText with Webdriver java

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ! operator

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
 if(!element.getText().contains("text to match"))
  {
  //code......
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the invisibilityOfElementLocated, like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, EXPLICIT_TIMEOUT).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));
```